# Linq Where is not recognizing operator overloads with custom object

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

I have a private class, User that implements an interface, IQMUser, with

```
    public static bool operator ==( User a, User b ) { return Equals( a, b ); }
    public static bool operator !=( User a, User b ) { return !Equals( a, b ); }
    public override bool Equals ( object obj )
    {
        User other = obj as User;
        return m_LMUser.UserID == other.m_LMUser.UserID;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode ( )
    {
        return m_LMUser.GetHashCode ( );
    }
```

User is a member of a public class, UserManager, which has GetUsers( ), which returns `IList<IQMUser>`.  In another class, I have

```
    IQMUser otherUser = UserManager.GetUsers( )
        .Where( u => u != CurrentUser )
        .FirstOrDefault( );
```

Now, I know for a fact that GetUsers returns an object that has the same m_LMUser.UserID as CurrentUser.  However, the test u != CurrentUser is always true, even in that case.

I have set breakpoints at each of the operator overloads and the Equals override in User, but none of them hit.

I then changed the query to

```
    IQMUser otherUser = UserManager.GetUsers( )
        .Where( u => !u.Equals( CurrentUser ) )
        .FirstOrDefault( );
```

This hits the overridden Equals method as expected.

What is wrong with my operator overloads that Linq doesn't even hit them?

Comment: What's the type of `UserManager.GetUsers()`?

Comment: Well that explains it then - you would see exactly the same thing if you tried it with any variables of type `IQMUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your inheritance hierarchy correctly, the type in the "Where" seems to be `IQMUser` (the base class), while the `operator ==` is implemented on the subclass `User`.

Since `operator ==` is ***not virtual***, the Linq Where expression with type `IQMUser` will run the `IQMUser operator ==` instead of the one implemented on `User`.

Equals on the other hand *is* virtual and the override works as it should, allowing it to work correctly if you call it directly instead.

Comment: I edited the original question to clarify that IQMUser is an Interface, not a base class.  Thus, I cannot specify an operator == overload for IQMUser.

Comment: @KellyCline If IQMUser is an interface, you'll most likely have to settle for `Equals` in your case, since you can't implement a correct static `operator ==` on it, and since it's a static operator it can't be virtual. You may be able to get away with making IQMUser into an abstract base class where `operator ==` calls the virtual `Equals`, but that seems an awful lot of work not to have to type `Equals`.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't mind settling for Equals as long as I understand why I had to.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, your == implementation is calling the static Object.Equals method rather than your instance equals method. This will check if both references point to the same piece of memory (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx)

Change it to:

```
public static bool operator ==( User a, User b ) { return a.Equals(b); }
public static bool operator !=( User a, User b ) { return !a.Equals(b); }
```

you should also change your equals method to this:

```
public override bool Equals ( object obj )
{
    User other = obj as User;
    return !Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null) && m_LMUser.UserID == other.m_LMUser.UserID;
}
```

Comment: Uhhh stack overflow ;-) "other != null" will call operator ==

Comment: That one has hit me more than once. A stackoverflow kills the web server process without warning.

Comment: Although there may be something wrong in the implementation of the overloaded operators, the problem remains that they are not even called.